# How to place a view on top of another view with centers of both view aligned in constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

***Layout:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="256dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**How to place the first view (red box) exactly on top of the second view (blue box) in a way such that the centers of both views align vertically.**

**Expected Layout:** (Centers should be aligned) (Not aligned in Screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to align view1 relative to view2. So view2 will have a sort of absolute position and then the view1 will align itself relative to view2.

This would be the constraints for the view1:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view2"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/view2"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/view2"
```

And then the layout should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/view2"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="256dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Another solution could be using the chain property, you can see more in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-chain)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you want to be able to move the blue box around, change the red box to this:

```
  <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view2" />
```

Comment: My bad...have added a screenshot...please check the edited question